# Returning a value

Tags: c

```
int lerCoordenadasFich( char bairroCoord[ ][ COLUNAS ][ 50 ], int linhas,
                        char *fichIn ){

   int contaLinhas=0;
   int contaColunas=0;
   FILE *fCoord;

   if( ( fCoord = fopen( fichIn, "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
      printf( "Nao foi possivel abrir o ficheiro.\n" );
      return 0;
   }
   else {
      while( contaLinhas < linhas) {
         while( contaColunas < COLUNAS) {
               fgets(bairroCoord[contaLinhas][contaColunas], 50, fCoord);
               contaColunas++;
         }
            contaLinhas++;
            contaColunas=0;
      }
      fclose(fCoord);
      return 1;
   }
}
```

I have this function that reads from a file...
The problem is I need to

```
printf("%s", bairroCoord[0][1] );
```

in function main, but it will print nothing... However it will print correctly if inside this function. How can I solve this? Also it is a requirement that I return 1.

Comment: `bairroCoord` must be a pointer or a reference (When you are on c++). Right now, you use a local copy of it, that gets discarded upon return.

Comment: how would I do that? not sure if understanding... sorry

Comment: Make bairroCoord global ... quickest way

Comment: @Henno it's a function argument and (a pointer to the first element of) an array, not a local.

Comment: Show your `main`. Also, what does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: @n.m. But as its passed by value (not by reference) a local copy is made by the compiler.

Comment: @Henno arrays are never passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not passing array correctly. The way I can see in `lerCoordenadasFich` function your array `bairroCoord[ ][ COLUNAS ][ 50 ]` is three dimensional while in printf your array is two dimensional and you cannot pass array without using a pointer.

Show how you are declaring this array and calling `lerCoordenadasFich` only then we can find the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are no problem with main function as belows:

```
#define COLUNAS 2

int main ()

{

char filename[20] = "myfile.txt";

char bairroCoord[10][ COLUNAS ][ 50 ];

lerCoordenadasFich(bairroCoord,2,filename);
printf("%s", bairroCoord[0][1] );
return 0;
}
```

You can compare to your main function.